# Search not refreshing on the input by symfony 6.2

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

The thing that I want to do is a dynamic `searchbar` in `symfony` with `ajax`. I already have a filter system and I want the `searchbar` to work with it. I'm trying to do that in **ajax + symfony 6.2**. My `PHP` version is `8.1.10`.

The code in my controller est: https://sharemycode.io/c/f4341e6

The code in my twig est: https://sharemycode.io/c/879139d

the code in my JS*: https://sharemycode.io/c/1615e4d

the code in my form: https://sharemycode.io/c/aa9a8d0

for the Repo*: https://sharemycode.io/c/d29c882

The problem here is that the search don't refresh when I write in the input (nothing happen). Maybe the problem is from the JavaScript?

I tried to `vardump` the result in controller, I have it, but this is only when I send the form `searchbar`.

Comment: use Dev Tool to inspect what's being sent for your AJAX call

Comment: I think that my ajax send nothing to the controller